# Odoo Missing Dependencies: web.ControlPanelMixin

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I'm trying to install some module In Odoo 13 Community. The dependency `'web.ControlPanelMixin'` is missing, I'm trying to fing the problem, so far I got no succes.
The JavaScript Code:

```
odoo.define('crm_dashboard.dashboard', [
  'web.core',
  'web.framework',
  'web.session',
  'web.ajax',
  'web.ActionManager',
  'web.view_registry',
  'web.Widget',
  'web.AbstractAction',
  'web.ControlPanelMixin'
], function (require) {
  "use strict";
  var core = require('web.core');
  var framework = require('web.framework');
  var session = require('web.session');
  var ajax = require('web.ajax');
  var ActionManager = require('web.ActionManager');
  var view_registry = require('web.view_registry');
  var Widget = require('web.Widget');
  var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');
  var ControlPanelMixin = require('web.ControlPanelMixin');
  var QWeb = core.qweb;
  ...
});
```

I tried searching for where is `'web.ControlPanelMixin'` declared:

```
[odoo-13.0]$ grep -rnw ./ -e 'ControlPanelMixin'
./doc/reference/javascript_reference.rst:2221:        var ControlPanelMixin = require('web.ControlPanelMixin');
./doc/reference/javascript_reference.rst:2224:        var ClientAction = AbstractAction.extend(ControlPanelMixin, {
./doc/reference/javascript_reference.rst:2262:- add ControlPanelMixin in the widget:
./doc/reference/javascript_reference.rst:2266:        var ControlPanelMixin = require('web.ControlPanelMixin');
./doc/reference/javascript_reference.rst:2268:        var MyClientAction = AbstractAction.extend(ControlPanelMixin, {
./doc/reference/javascript_reference.rst:2277:        var SomeClientAction = Widget.extend(ControlPanelMixin, {
./mymodules/odoo_crm_dashboard/static/src/js/crm_dashboard.js:11:    'odoo.web.ControlPanelMixin'
./mymodules/odoo_crm_dashboard/static/src/js/crm_dashboard.js:25:var ControlPanelMixin = require('web.ControlPanelMixin');
./mymodules/odoo_crm_dashboard/static/src/js/crm_dashboard.js:31:var CRMDashboardView = AbstractAction.extend(ControlPanelMixin, {
```

Thank you!

Comment: remove odoo from odoo.web.ControlPanelMixin, it's web.ControlPanelMixin

Comment: I'll remove it, but it was an attempt to fix the problem. The dependency still missing

Comment: Have you got the solution @Nomad ??
I am facing similar problem.
ControlPanelMixin is missing from web/static/src/js/chrome  of Odoo13

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake:

```
odoo.define('crm_dashboard.dashboard', [
    'web.core',
    'web.framework',
    'web.session',
    'web.ajax',
    'web.ActionManager',
    'web.view_registry',
    'web.Widget',
    'web.AbstractAction',
    'web.ControlPanelMixin'
]
```

It is **web.ControlPanelMixin** not `odoo.web.ControlPanelMixin`

You can review this [documentation](https://doc.flectrahq.com/reference/javascript.html)

Comment: It was an attempt to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ControlPanelMixin was removed in Odoo 13.0.

Instead of extending from it, objects can now use `hasControlPanel: true`. See the [Odoo source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website/static/src/js/backend/dashboard.js#L33) for an example.